# maximizing KL divergence as the objective function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler

As far as I know, the most common approach to train neural networks is to minimize the KL divergence between the data distribution and the output of the model distribution which results in minimizing the cross-entropy. Now assume we have a binary classification task, our goal can be optimizing a network such that the KL divergence between the two class distributions is maximized. I want to know is there any basic difference in these two different approaches? and can we optimize the latter approach explicitly with regards to the parameters of a neural network?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that for $KL(p||q)$ minimum over $p$ is attained (it's zero when the $p = q$) but maximum may not exist (or make sense in usual way).

KL-divergence is a convex function. Convex functions on bounded sets attain their minima. There is a whole branch of math that deals with convex optimization.

The same doesn't hold for maxima - for KL divergence: let $$p \sim Bernouli(1)$$ $$q_t \sim Bernoulli(t)$$ Then $$\lim_t KL(p||q_t) = -1 log(\frac{1}{t}) - 0log(\frac{0}{1-t}) = \lim_t - log(\frac{1}{t}) = \infty{}$$

BTW one other way to look at it is that KL-divergence works as sort of distance - minimizing distance usually makes sense, but maximizing it may not, if you don't pose any constraints, because the space where you measure your distance might be unbounded, so the distances are arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, but we don't need to attain the maximum, we can just move in that direction. Minimizing convex functions is easy, because of their properties, however, we know that the loss function (KL divergence with respect to the parameters of the NN, not its distribution) is not convex and minimizing that is not easy.  In fact, if you look at the NN as a mapping function, we want the NN to discriminate more between classes, right? so it is very intuitive to try to maximize a distance metric for that. (it can be KL or EM distance)

Comment: This is not what happens when training a model - when you train a model you get a fixed target distribution, and you try your model's distribution to match that, thus you want your predictions to be *closer* to target.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to look at the models, but I mean this can be an alternative way for optimizing a network, can't be?

Comment: Yeah, but the one using KL divergence actually has some theory behind it, namely maximum likelihood estimation, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Relation_to_log-likelihood)

Comment: Yeap, minimizing KL divergence or cross-entropy is equivalent to maximizing the log-likelihood, but I mean that it one way to formulate the problem. In that approach, we see the network as the estimator of the data generating distribution, but I want to know, is this view different from that one? and still valid?